# git error FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'git receive-pack'

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

I am using a git on windows, I can clone a repo but whenever I try to push I get this error
"FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'git receive-pack 'p/2025-s2-csharp/tp12-myname''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
I have tried to reclone the repo and to reinstall git but it didn't work. I can still push on the repo from another computer on this repo.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This error is coming from the server, not from your own machine. It needs to be fixed *on* the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by opening my git config globally with git "config --global --edit" it contained this part
"[remote "origin"]
receivepack = git receive-pack"
I just had to remove it and it fixed it.

Comment: Thank you!!! I had this nasty issue when trying to setup gitolite3, and this came up when I tried to push to the gitolite-admin repo. Life saver!